# Domains and setbuilder notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

We're learning about domains and setbuilder notation in school at the moment, and I want to make sure what I did was right.

My thought process:
\begin{align*}
-\frac12|4x - 8| - 1 &< -1 \\
-\frac12|4x - 8| &< 0 \\
|4x - 8| &> 0
\end{align*}
$x =$ all real numbers.

{real numbers} :

<||||||||||[0]|||||||||>

{x| x is any real number}

{whole numbers}

... <----[-2]---[-1]---[0]---[1]---[2]---> ...

{x|...-2,-1,0,1,2...}

Comment: I had to edit this to make the equations not run together, so I added [TeX markup](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117), which you might consider learning if you want to ask more questions. Alternatively, place your ASCII art inside a [code block](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Thanks.  Are you also telling me it's right?

Comment: There's not much organization, so it's hard to tell what you're asking. It's not true that every real number $x$ satisfies $|4x - 8| > 0$, and it seems like you might be saying that, but I was hoping someone else would write an answer (I'm surprised that this hasn't happened yet). I may yet do so after finishing this section of my book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's consider how absolute-value is defined:

$$
|a| = 
\begin{cases}
a, & \text{if } a \geq 0,
\\ -a, &\text{if } a \lt 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore,

$$4x-8 > +0\phantom{.}$$

$$4x-8 < -0.$$

Now, solve for $x$ to get the answer:

$$x > 2\phantom{.}$$

or $$x < 2.$$

Note: This is same as $$ x \neq 2.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just made me realize something important.  I was treating the greater-than sign as  a greater-than-or-equal-to sign.

Answer (score 1):

You get $|4x - 8| > 0$, which I agree with; now you want to find all $x$ satisfying this inequality. It's true that for any number $y$ we have $|y| \geq 0$, but equality can hold: $|y| = 0$ if and only if $y = 0$. Use this fact to find the single value $a$ of $x$ for which $|4x - 8| = 0$. In [set-builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) notation, I would write this as
\[
\{x \mid x \neq a\} \qquad \text{or, more carefully,} \qquad \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x \neq a\},
\]
replacing $a$ by the number you find.

Your representations of the real numbers look fine to me. There is always [controversy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number) over what "whole numbers" should mean, and I would call
\[
\{x \mid x = \ldots, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, \ldots\}
\]
the set of integers. Note the slight difference between your expression and mine.